# Excel function to join 2 columns in different file

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula

I'm new in Excel .

I want search matched values between F1.xlsx and F2.xlsx on the **id**. And write in the F2.xlsx the response on the id that exist in F1.xlsx.
Below a figure to represent my tables!.

[image: Excel files]

Any helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a basic `VLOOKUP` function. It does not make a difference whether you select a range in the same workbook or in a different workbook, Excel will take care of putting the correct file and worksheet references in the formula. So when you are writing the formula and need to select the range in a different workbook, just click on the workbook `F1.xlsx`, and select the range you want.

The formula itself (which you put in cell `D2` and then copy down):
`=VLOOKUP(B2;'FULL-PATH-TO-YOUR-FILE[F1.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$2:$C$7;3)`

But you do not need to actually write the entire reference to the lookup range, if you select the range manually (with your mouse), Excel will do this. The Full path will not be added unless you close the `F1.xlsx` file.

Comment: you can use the same formula to put the name in the second file (based on the ID)

Comment: @anayisse You're welcome. I added a comment that you can use the same formula to put the name in the second file (based on the ID)